# Eliminar el warning

Tags: reactjs

Necesito cambiar el estado del arreglo `selectionArray`, ya que cuando hago el push y cambio a otro componente me repite el ultimo elemento clicleado, por ello coloqué dentro del render el `if` y el `set state` pero la consola me envia el sigueinte warning:

> index.js:1437 Warning: Cannot update during an existing state
>   transition (such as within `render`). Render methods should be a pure
>   function of props and state

Soy nueva usando react no se si el cambio de estado esta mal ubicado

```
import React from "react";
import TableOrder from "../components/TableOrder";

class ButtonSelection extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      selectionArray: "",
      orderArray: []
    };
    this.addOrder = this.addOrder.bind(this);
  }

  addOrder(name, price) {
    this.setState({
      selectionArray: { name: name, price: price }
    });
  }
  render() {
    if (this.state.selectionArray !== "") {
      this.state.orderArray.push(this.state.selectionArray);
      this.setState({
        selectionArray: ""
      });
    }
    return (
      <>
        {this.props.newMenu.map((el, index) => (
          <button
            key={index}
            className="btn-breakfast"
            onClick={e => this.addOrder(el.name, el.price)}
          >
            <p>{el.name} </p>
            <p>${el.price}</p>
          </button>
        ))}
        <TableOrder listorder={this.state.orderArray} />
      </>
    );
  }
}

export default ButtonSelection;
```

Comment: cual es la linea que tira el error?

Comment: if(this.state.selectionArray !== ""){
  this.state.orderArray.push(this.state.selectionArray)
 this.setState({

  selectionArray: ""

  });
un warning

Comment: No debes modificar el estado directamente usando `this.state.orderArray.push`. Para ello crea una constante con un lista vacia `const nuevaLista = []`. Actualiza la nueva lista con el/los items nuevos que quieras en la nueva lista `nuevaLista.push(...)` y una vez hecho eso, actualiza el estado con `this.setState({ orderArray: nuevaLista})`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema es que no puedes utilizar la función `setState` dentro del método render, ya que estarías provocando un bucle infinito.

Pero siempre lo puedes hacer con el método [`componentDidUpdate`](https://es.reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidupdate) que recibe las `props` anteriores y el estado anterior.

Dentro de este método solo vamos a poder actualizar el estado de nuestro componente siempre y cuando esté envuelto en un condicional y si no entraremos en un bucle infinito y provocando renderizaciones innecesarias.

Por ejemplo:

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState){
   if(prevState.count !== prevState.count) {
     this.setState({ total: this.state.total +1 }) //Ejemplo muy basico y casi sin sentido
   }
 }
```

Bien sabiendo esto tu componente quedara algo así con un par de cambios.

```
import React from "react";
import TableOrder from "../components/TableOrder";

class ButtonSelection extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      selectionArray: "",
      orderArray: []
    };
    this.addOrder = this.addOrder.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
    if (this.state.selectionArray !== prevState.selectionArray) {
      if (this.state.selectionArray !== "") {
        this.state.orderArray.push(this.state.selectionArray);
        this.setState({
          selectionArray: ""
        });
      }
    }
  }

  addOrder(name, price) {
    this.setState({
      selectionArray: { name: name, price: price }
    });
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <>
        {this.props.newMenu.map((el, index) => (
          <button
            key={index}
            className="btn-breakfast"
            onClick={e => this.addOrder(el.name, el.price)}
          >
            <p>{el.name} </p>
            <p>${el.price}</p>
          </button>
        ))}
        <TableOrder listorder={this.state.orderArray} />
      </>
    );
  }
}

export default ButtonSelection;
```

Comment: Muchas gracias me funciono

Comment: ComponentDidMount no recibe esos parámetros verdad?

Comment: Si tienes razon, fallo mio porque no cambie a componentDidUpdate, ya he actualizado mi respuesta. Bien visto. Gracias.

Comment: Pero te entendi pense que lo habias colocado para ver si yo captaba, pero ya veo que no es asi :D @EugeniBejan